# merging Linux Kernel using CIL

Tags: linux-kernel, static-analysis, c-intermediate-language

I am trying to use CIL merger to merge Linux Kernel and run an analysis on it.
I tried this on different version of the kernel. each gave different errors.

#### Linux-3.4.2:

In Linux Kernel-3.4.2 source folder I used the following command

> $ make CC="cilly --save-temps --dofsvd --merge"

and it gave the following error

> /home/srikanth/projects2test/linux-3.4.2/arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h[345:0-0]
>   : syntax error Parsing errorFatal error: exception
>   Frontc.ParseError("Parse error")

error is due to this line:

> asm goto(... : : "i" (bit) : : t_no);

It is unable to recognize the "asm" instructions. I googled for it. In BLAST bug reports ([here](http://forge.ispras.ru/issues/1323)) I found that we can use some aspectator options to prevent such constructs. But I don't know what options to use. How can I Ignore asm(or any other constructs that are not supported)?

#### Linux-2.4.5:

In Linux Kernel-2.4.5 source folder I used the following command

> $ make CC="cilly --save-temps --dofsvd --merge"

The above command gave the following error

> Makefile:229: arch/x86_64/Makefile: No such file or directory make:
>   *** No rule to make target `arch/x86_64/Makefile'.  Stop.

for this I included ARCH=i386 option to make file.

> $ make ARCH=i386 CC="cilly --save-temps --dofsvd --merge"

and it said

> init/main.c:1:0: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64
>   instruction set

How to fix this error?

I want to run the analysis on Linux Kernel (any version). I am unable to merge it due to these errors. please help me fix these problems.

Comment: Hi. Have you found an answer to this yet? Thanks.